# No match for 'operator==' C++ compile error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Another question from a C++ newbie.

I'm receiving a compiler error "No match for 'operator=='" for the following block of code

```
void swap(Team t1, Player p1, Team t2, Player p2){
    Player new_t1[11];
    Player new_t2[11];
    for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
        new_t1[i] = t1.get_player(i);
        new_t2[i] = t2.get_player(i);
        if(new_t1[i] == p1){
            new_t1[i] = p2;
        }
        if(new_t2[i] == p2){
            new_t2[i] = p1;
        }
    }

    cout << "Players swapped.";
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you implemented the `operator==` function for `Player` class?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know what it means for the two players to be the same. Are they the same if their names are the same? Or their IDs? You need to define == operator for `class Player`.

```
bool operator == (const Player &p1, const Player &p2)
{
   if( / * evaluate their equality */)
     return true;
   else
     return false;
}
```

Also, I don't think your `swap()` function has any effect right now. You may want to change it  to accept `Team`s and `Player`s by reference.

Comment: `const` is illegal on a free function.

Comment: what if we just want to check if it is null or not

Answer (score 8):

You need to **overload** the `==` operator for your `Player` class. In other words, you need to tell the compiler how to compare within your `Player` object.

Example:

```
bool MyClass::operator==(const MyClass &other) const {
    ...  // Compare the values, and return a bool result.
}
```

Might help you: [Operator Overload](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
if(new_t1[i] == p1){
```

The compiler doesn't know how to compare two `Player` objects, unless you explicitly tell it by implementing `operator==`. See the "Comparison operators" section of [this guide](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html).