# Why is there an error "no match for 'operator==' " when I do not have a variable or anything else named that?

Tags: c++

I have been trying to make a password hash simulator which hashes passwords, and when I try to run it with this `if` statement:

```
 if (password == letters[just]){
            justtwo++;
            cout << letters[just]
}
```

It works perfectly fine, but if I put:

```
 if (password[justtwo] == letters[just]){
            justtwo++;
            cout << letters[just]
```

It says:

> no match for 'operator=='

Even though I didn't put `operator==` anywhere.

(BTW, I am putting `justtwo` to see if I can isolate the letters of the password so I can add a list that changes those letters into random gibberish)

I don't know why it does this, but it does. BTW, it's my first time here, so I'm kind of a noob to this website, and this is my first ever C++ program.

If anyone is curious, here is the code. The reason for all the random words is because they are placeholders, and when I figure everything out I will put what actually goes there. :)

```
    string letters[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
    string password;
    cout << "lol:";
    cin >> password;
    bool white = true;
    int just = -1;
    int justtwo = 0;
    while (white){
        just++;
        if (password[justtwo] == letters[just]){
            justtwo++;
            cout << letters[just];
        }
    }
    cout << "lol";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag C++ questions as C. These are two different languages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No match for 'operator==' C++ compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149059/no-match-for-operator-c-compile-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it says "no match for 'operator==' " as an error even though I didnt put operator== anywere.

Ah, but you did! In c++, `A == B` is shorthand for the function `operator==(A,B)` (or, if A is an object, `A.operator==(B)`). [This is how operator "overloading" works.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) It allows you, the programmer, to define what the equals operator means when called on two user-defined objects (or a user-defined object and plain old data, or whatever). What you wrote:

```
if (password[justtwo] == letters[just]){
```

translates to:

```
if (operator==(password[justtwo], letters[just])){
```

The left-hand operand is actually a `char`, because the `string` class defines another operator called `operator[](size_type pos)` [which returns the character at the given position](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at). You are trying to compare a `char` to a `string`, and that operation is not defined.

The reason the first version you wrote works is because both the left-hand and right-hand operands of the `==` are `string` objects:

```
string letters[] = ...;  // letters is an array of string objects
string password;         // password is a string
if (password == letters[0]){  // letters[0] is a string
   ...
```

If you take a look at the documentation of the `std::string` class, you'll see that [there is an `operator==(string, string)` method defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).

You have a few options for fixing this code. You can just make `letters` a `string` instead of an array of `string`s:

```
string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

That way, when you write `password[justtwo] == letters[just]`, you are comparing a `char` with a `char`, which is a defined operation.

Another way of fixing the code is to make `letters` an array of `char`s:

```
char letters[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', ...};
```

This gets you to the same result as above. You could also use a `c`-style `char *` and achieve the same results.

Finally, if you want to be really tricky (*I do not recommend doing this, however*), you can define an equality operator between a `char` and a `string` like this:

```
bool operator==(const char& lhs, const std::string& lhs){
    return rhs.size() == 1 && rhs[0] == lhs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of `letters` is array of string. So the the type of `letters[just]` is string.
And the type of `password` is string.

So the first version of the code works.

```
 if (password == letters[just]){
            justtwo++;
            cout << letters[just]
}
```

And the type of `password[justtwo]` is `const char&` (As you are new to C++, you can consider it as char for now).

The compiler throws the error as the type of `password[justtwo]` is different from  `letters[just]`.

Answer (score 0):

This compares a `std::string` with `std::string` (implicitly converted from `const char*`), which is a valid comparison:

```
password == letters[just]
```

This compares a `const char` with `std::string`, and that's not a valid comparison:

```
password[justtwo] == letters[just]
```

If you want to compare a substring, you'll need to ask for it:

```
password.substr(justtwo, 1) == letters[just]
```

Of course you don't need `std::string` here, you could either use an array of characters, or you could use a singular string and compare character to character:

```
string letters = "abcd...xyz";
```

Then you can easily compare one to another as `const char` vs. `const char`:

```
password[justtwo] == letters[just]
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `password` is of type `std::string` and `letters` is of type `vector` of `strings`. So when you compare

`if (password == letters[just])`

you are comparing `string` to another `string` because `[..]` takes out one value from letters which is actually a `string`.

But when you write condition as

`password[justtwo] == letters[just]`

what you end up comparing is a single character with another `string`. This part `password[justtwo]` will take out a single character out of `password` variable since it's a string of characters.

The error message signifying usage of `operator==` is just your usage of `==` operator.

---

Maybe you want to store actual letters in variable `letters`? Then use a `vector<char> letters = {'a', 'b'}`. Then your second condition will run fine because you will be comparing character to another character.